# Why the downvotes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

OK, last time I wanted to identify TV series, I was asking for it, because I remember very little. But this time I am clueless.

Question in discussion: [Why did Dusty not use the internet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60616/why-did-dusty-not-use-the-internet)

It currently has -2 votes and no comments. Worst part is, that I have no clue what might be wrong.

So, how to avoid asking bad question about [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) in rather old movies?

Comment: Total guess since I didn't see the question until I saw this.... people are probably struggling a little bit to apply a simple 'real world' solution to a fantasy animated movie.  I've not seen the movie in question, and perhaps this is not as good an analogy as I think - but I wonder whether its similar to "Why didn't Lightning McQueen just use a cellphone to contact his team in Cars"

Comment: Well at least with the phone, it can be explained that not everyone had cellphone and Lightning could depend on the fact that "all in my team have a phone, so I do not need it" celebrity approach. But I kinda get it, that I am trying to apply normal world solutions to fairy tale. Still I consider it bit a plot hole...

Comment: But this is a clear 'suspension of disbelief' problem ... where you think the characters should do something but they don't. A realism question is hardest in a movie that is set in something close to the real world. However in the case of an animated fantasy movie, the rules of the world are not necessarily similar to the real world, therefore its easier for the writer to make decisions like this and for the viewer to assume that this is ok.  You can't assume a world where living cars and planes exist to be like ours - so you just have to go with the plot the writers give you.

Comment: That said, downvotes without comments are less useful.

Comment: And its not a question of being an 'old movie' ... this movie is 2 years old.